# Analytical solution for a separable scalar nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the scalar ODE
$$ \dot x(t) = -x(t)\sqrt{1+x(t)^4} \quad \text{with} \quad x(0) = x_0\in\mathbb{R}$$
for all $t\geq 0$. This ODE is separable:
$$ -\int \frac{{\rm d}x}{x\sqrt{1+x^4}} = \int^{t}_{0}{\rm d}s$$
so we get the implicit equation
$$ \frac{1}{2}{\rm arctanh}\left({\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right) + \mathbb{c} = t.$$
We proceed with the manipulation to get
$$ x(t) = \left(  \tanh^{2}(2t-2\mathbb{c}) -1 \right)^{1/4}.$$
At this point, I realize I have an issue... the argument $\tanh^2(y)-1=-{\rm sech}^2(y)$ is negative, no matter what $\mathbb{c}$ is so I get a complex solution. I am looking for a real solution for all real initial conditions $x_0$. Is this possible?

**Edit**

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%20%3D%20-x%20sqrt%281%2Bx%5E4%29) gives me four different solutions which all have a similar negative argument in $(\cdot)^{1/4}$ which is puzzling.

Moreover, isn't the right-hand side at least Lipschitz continuous so uniqueness is assured?

Comment: Did you check your integration? Also I think you mean *arctanh*.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+-1%2F%28x+sqrt%281%2Bx%5E4%29%29

Comment: Thanks, my mistake---let me edit. Still, this does not change my problem I think as the following line assumed I was working with arctanh.

Comment: The mistake comes the moment you write arctanh of $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ which is outside the range of tanh. The wolfram link above fixes this

Comment: I don't mean to be obtuse here, but even if I replace arctanh by arccoth I still have a formula which is not valid for $x_0=0$. The curve $x(t)=0$ is a solution and the right-hand side is at least Lipschitz continuous, so shouldn't there be a solution that also captures $x_0=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the observations in the comments, here is my proposed answer.
First, for $x\neq 0$ we have
$$ -\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{x \sqrt{1+x^4}} = \frac{1}{2}{\rm arccoth}\left( \sqrt{x^4+1}\right) + \mathbb{c}  = \int_{0}^{t} {\rm d}s = t.$$

Using the initial condition $x(0)=x_{0}\neq 0$ and solving for $\mathbb{c}$ gives
$$ \mathbb{c} = g(x_{0}) = \frac{1}{2}{\rm arccoth}^2\left(\sqrt{1+x_{0^4}}\right).$$

Solving for $x$ and ignoring the imaginary roots yields
$$ x = \pm\left(\coth^{2}(2\mathbb{c}-2t)-1\right)^\frac{1}{4}  = \pm ({\rm csch}^{2}\left( 2g(x_0)-2t \right))^\frac{1}{4}$$.

Which leads to the solution of the ODE for all $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ being
$$x(t) =  {\rm sign}(x_0)({\rm csch}^{2}\left( 2g(x_0)-2t \right))^\frac{1}{4}.$$